# How to fix "Failed to execute OPTIONS" in quarkus reactive endpoint?

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

I'm developing an API using Quarkus 0.24.0 and the following extensions : [cdi, reactive-pg-client, rest-client, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, security, vertx]

Here's one of the route I've implemented :

```
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UsersResource {

    @Inject
    KeycloakUsersService keycloakUsersService;

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed({"ADMIN"})
    public CompletionStage<Response> getUsers(@QueryParam("search") String searchQuery) {
        return keycloakUsersService.getUsers(searchQuery)
                .thenApply(Response::ok)
                .thenApply(Response.ResponseBuilder::build)
                 .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    logger.error("Wut ?" + throwable.getMessage());
                    return Response.status(500).entity("Something wrong happened while retrieving users from Keycloak : " + throwable.getCause()).build();
                });
    }
}
```

Everything was running smoothly until I started to consume my API using Angular. Before making the API call there's an OPTIONS request, which fails :

```
 Failed executing OPTIONS /users: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.DefaultOptionsMethodException: RESTEASY003655: No resource method found for options, return OK with Allow header
```

I've tried to add the following in application.properties, without success :

```
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:8080
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET, OPTIONS, POST
```

How can I fix the OPTIONS request ? Is there a way to globally handle the OPTIONS requests ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a CORS issue. Did you tried this?

```
quarkus.http.cors = true
```

Comment: Yep, that changes nothing.